# I'm looking to do an infinite scrolling loop custom code in Webflow project

Tags: webflow

I am trying to create this automatic, infinite scroll; example on this site (logos at the bottom of page): https://www.speedgeek.com/

I'm trying to add custom code to a Webflow project. The code I have added is in the Team page body.

You can view my read-only webflow project here to see the div and section elements:
https://preview.webflow.com/preview/apartmentlist-com-about?utm_medium=preview_link&utm_source=designer&utm_content=apartmentlist-com-about&preview=f2723eca4f11da331474a050a7cb8940&pageId=5d7f470ca3db0876bf3b861c&mode=preview

Live link here:
https://apartmentlist-com-about.webflow.io/about/team

Any help is much appreciated!

Cheers,
Bec